# Уведомления по WebSockets на разные сервера (домены)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Пытаюсь отправить оповещения для нескольких серверов которые расположены на разных доменах, но вебсокеты отрабатываются только для того сервера, с которого я отправляю. Сам сервер с вебсокетами находится отдельно от всех остальных.
C сервера **site1** я отправляю запрос

```
var socket = io('http://server-websocket/', { transports: ['websocket'] });            
socket.emit('send-request', data);
```

В ответ на сервер **site1** данные приходят успешно

```
var socket = io('http://server-websocket/', { transports: ['websocket'] });
socket.on('send-request', function(answer) {        
    //success
});
```

А на **site2** они не приходят в ответ, и точно так же наоборот. Если с **site2** я отправляю данные, то на **site2** ответ приходит успешно, а на **site1** ничего не происходит.
Как можно реализовать уведомления что бы при отправки с одного сервера, отправка сообщений уходила на все сервера?

Comment: Вы с чего решили, что запросы не приходят? Тут легко можно сделать на бэкэнде так, что по referer будет фильтрация, с точки зрения безопасности часто так делают.

Comment: Потому что данные приходят только для того сайта, с которого отправляются, а необходимо что бы отправленные данные с одного сайта уходили на все сервера.

Comment: Приходят куда? Вы их tcpdump смотрите? Если нет, то есть куча вариантов как они могут быть отфильтрованы ещё до начала обработки бэкэнде, и во многих местах их не будет видно.

Comment: Должны приходить на клиент, я смотрю их в DOM

Comment: Из Вашего кода видно, что устанавливается соединение на server-host,   приходит некий request, и даётся некий answer. Отслеживали ли Вы на стороне клиента и на сервере, что соединение действительно устанавливается?

Comment: Да, оно устанавливается, иначе как данные между ними ходили бы? Есть ещё момент который я не указал, сервера находятся на разных доменах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл в документации ответ на свой вопрос, с помощью **broadcast** можно отправить сообщение всем остальным клиентам кроме того, который отправляет запрос. https://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages

```
socket.on('send-request', function(answer) {
    socket.emit('send-request', answer);
    socket.broadcast.emit('send-request', answer); // он отправляет всем остальным.
});
```

Comment: А при чем тут вообще разные домены?..

Comment: Есть проекты которые находятся на одном сервере, но хостятся в разных доменах. Я подумал что это может иметь значение, поэтому указал.

Comment: Да, но без этой строки у вас и в пределах одного домена работать как вы хотели не могло!

Comment: Без какой строки? Если речь идёт о broadcast, то без неё работало.

Comment: Про которую вы в ответе написали.

Comment: Почему вот это **socket.emit('send-request', answer);** не должно работать?

Comment: @Vayas вы сообщали только одному пользователю о событии, а не всем. Тут речь не о разных доменах. Сокет отправит всем слушателям где бы они не были (если стоят права на кросс-доменную отправку)

Comment: Вы не могли бы показать пример?